# Development machine url does not reflect "dev" part in the url

Tags: nginx

I have two machines, and they are served by a master machine. The master machine defines the first machine `10.10.0.59`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 200M;
        server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
        server_name_in_redirect off;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.0.59;
        proxy_redirect default;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location ^~ /dev/ {

        proxy_pass http://10.10.0.56;
        proxy_redirect default;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        rewrite /dev/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

The `dev` machine is `10.19.9.56` and I need to add (most likely) `/dev/` to the url path, so that I can browse it by `http://public_domain/dev/.....`

Each of these machines has several apps running.

With this new rule, I can go on by `http://public_domain/dev/app1/` but all the links on that page will point to, for example, `http://public_domain/app1/login` which is server#1.

What else is wrong? Thanks.

Should I setup a new server clause? If I do, do I need to open a different port because the these two `location` blocks are inside the same server clause and listening on 80.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the trailing / on your [proxy_pass](http://wiki.nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) directives.  That tells proxy_pass to replace the part of the url that matched the location (/dev) with the provided path (/).  It doesn't make a difference in your location / because it's replacing / with /.  If you just replace your current line with

```
proxy_pass http://10.10.0.59;
```

Then it will not process the url before passing it to the backend.

Comment: Thank you. I've just updated my post. Do I need a different server block? I have only one and I've tried to rewrite.

Comment: Unless you can update your app to use relative uri paths everywhere or live under /dev/ on the backend, you probably will need to use a second server.  The rewrite you're doing now is doing the same thing as the trailing / you originally had on the proxy_pass

Comment: You mean second physical server, or second server block? Thanks

Comment: Second server block.  server { server_name dev.domain.com; ... }

Answer (score -1):

**Update**: My answer is wrong. But, I'm leaving it here so that whoever sees this wouldn't make my mistake!

`location /` block should probably be the last block of any `server`. In your configuration, it comes first. That's probably the reason for the issue you described. So, please try the following...

```
server {
        server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
        server_name_in_redirect off;

        location /dev {
                proxy_pass http://10.10.0.59/;
                    .........
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://10.10.0.56/;
                     ........
```

Comment: The order of static location blocks does not matter.  See http://wiki.nginx.org/r/location

Comment: @kolbyjack You're right. I just tested it myself on a demo setup. Thanks for sharing the right information.